# jQuery infinite preloader until AJAX success is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, input

So I'm using jQuery [**knob**](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) for a project of mine to indicate progresses around. This time I need to kind of simulate a progress, so an exact progress will not be given, instead I will be using *knob's* `× 'cursor' mode` which can be seen at the website. It's that partially filled circle.

In my HTML the whole thing would look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="progress" value="0" data-cursor="true" data-displayInput="false" data-thickness=".3" data-width="128" data-height="128" data-fgColor="#ad3b3b" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#e2e2e2" />

<script>$('#progress').knob();</script>
```

The result would be similar to this:

[image: Progress]

Now I want to use this as a preloader. I want the `value="0"` from the `input` tag to increase and once it hits 100, it goes back to 0 repeating the whole process. This would look pretty slick and awesome.

This preloader would keep rotating until I tell it to stop with a `success` event of a `$.ajax` request.

---

**What I need help with:**

The only thing I need help with is make the progress rotate infinitely until I tell it to stop. The stopping part is not a big deal, but I don't know how to trigger the rotation with jQuery/JS

Thank you.

Comment: Try This,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988768/jquery-knob-update-value-with-animate

Or

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955708/how-to-display-units-with-jquery-knob

Thanks.

Comment: @bilgibilisim Those are quite helpful, but still not quite similar to what I'm looking for.