# How to create a circular progress bar over a image with only css?

Tags: css

I´m trying to create a circular progress bar over a image, like the image attached.

I´d like when 100%, hide progress. Any help?

[image]

Comment: where is your code share it

Comment: put your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Could you please provide feedback for my answer (accept if you like it or comment if need something else)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS animation for this. This solution uses animated circle halves:

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRV6Q.jpg");
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle__half {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle__half:before {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
  background-color: lime;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  /* hidden by default */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  opacity: 0.65;
  animation-name: rotate-circle-half;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.circle__half--right {
  transform: scale(-1, -1);
}

.circle .circle__half--right:before {
  animation-name: rotate-circle-half--right;
}

/* show half of circle half of the time */
@keyframes rotate-circle-half {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-circle-half--right {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle__half"></div>
  <div class="circle__half circle__half--right"></div>
</div>
```

Also if you want smooth circle hiding you can add animation for circle halves:

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRV6Q.jpg");
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle__half {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: hide-smoothly;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.circle__half:before {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
  background-color: lime;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  /* hidden by default */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  opacity: 0.65;
  animation-name: rotate-circle-half;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.circle__half--right {
  transform: scale(-1, -1);
}

.circle .circle__half--right:before {
  animation-name: rotate-circle-half--right;
}

/* show half of circle half of the time */
@keyframes rotate-circle-half {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-circle-half--right {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes hide-smoothly {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="circle__half"></div>
  <div class="circle__half circle__half--right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that's capable of doing it: [`jQuery.knob`](http://anthonyterrien.com/demo/knob/).

```js
$(function() {
  $(".knob").knob();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Knob/1.2.13/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
<input class="knob" data-width="150" data-width="100" data-displayInput="false" data-displayPrevious="true" data-fgColor="#87ceeb" data-skin="tron" data-thickness="15" value="75" />
```

If you want it animated, you can change the `value` of the input! Just take your mouse over the knob and use your mouse wheel to scroll it. Or see it animated here: [jQuery Knob update value with animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988768/jquery-knob-update-value-with-animate)

Comment: Hi Praveen, thanks, but I can´t use jquery. I´m using Ionic projet. I need to do it only with css.

Comment: @AndrePavini Sorry, you won't be able to do it with just CSS. You can use SVG animation if you are okay, but even for that, you need to use JavaScript. Eh, we need to find something that works with ionic. You didn't mention that bud! **Not possible using pure CSS sorry! `:(`**

Comment: Apparently this is not CSS solution.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Yes, obviously. But well... Your answer is good.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thank you. The main issue of your answer that it doesn't answers original question even with jQuery. If you would demonstrate how this plugin elegantly animates circular progress bar and then progress bar disappears this will be much much better.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Thanks for your feedback bro... `:)`